# eGalax multitouch and calibration 14.04

Tags: xorg, multi-touch, touchscreen

I'm doing some kiosk touchscreen school project.

I have eGalax touchscreen and I'm using the latest eGalax drivers. 
I followed this tutorial : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen
I'm using eGTouchU to calibrate screen and not xinput_calibrator because its somehow very painfull to calibrate if I use portrait resolution i.e. SwapAxes in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf

But anyway I expected the original drivers to work better as default (usbhidtouch) but it feels and looks the same. ( one tutorial mentions blacklisting usbhidtouch driver while the other one instructs to put them in /etc/modules ?? ) Setting sensitivity doesn't really have any effects. Besides that it was supposed to be Multitouch. 
Also I was trying to find where this program stores its calibration values but no success. I found /etc/eGalax0.param (or smth) binary file that changes every time I run calibration, but when I tried to change it with the previous false calibrated file it didn't have any effect (before and after reboot) - by that I assume that this is not the right file.

So how can I bring better touch expariance to my Kiosk ? eGalax was supposed to be a good touchscreen but it doesn't work well. I'm using Google Chrome as player because it can scroll websites instead of selecting text (like in FF). I know Ubuntu is not Android ( I've tried Android x86 but it has other limitations ) but how about multitouch gestures ? I heard about touchegg ? any opinion ?